# Votes counted as views bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips

When I view [my favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46011?tab=favorites#tab-top) the [top one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) says **2** kvotes, but the hover text says "1556 views". The question itself has 1556 votes, 122,155 views.

[image: Screenshot of the described bug]

It's displaying the right number when you hover over votes, but labeling them "views" instead of "votes".

Small bug, I know, but I thought I would let someone know.

---

### Update

This is marked as `status completed` but it is still showing when I look in my favorites (10/14/10):
[image]

Is possible it was fixed on the main pages but not the profile pages?

Comment: I just bumped that question, and the same tooltip error occurs when the question is on the main page, as well as in the favourites listing.

Comment: Geezers, one more edit and we blast this to Community Wiki. In any case, it seems to be anywhere with that tooltip. The [original author's question list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/11110/karan) also shows kvotes, and also has the erroneous tooltip.

Comment: 9 minutes alive - 6 edits. Good rate!

Comment: @Grace There was impressively little crossover though, we just all wanted to add different things :)

Comment: @mmyers: Did you push the `[tooltip]` --> `[tooltips]` synonym through during your editing?

Comment: @Jon Seigel: No, apparently it was already in place. (And you tagged it "tooptip".)

Comment: SORRY I didn't mean to put this into CW mode. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Comment: I am still seeing it say *2045 views* here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/46011?tab=favorites

Comment: @john sorry, fixed for real this time

Comment: yep confirmed. :)